quick effect animation render doesnt show the smoke, but the image render and preview do. (EEVEE)
My simulation is quick effect: fire and smoke, in eevee it has a particle system driving the inflow, and resolution was set to 64. I baked the simulation and particles but when I rendered the animation (250 frames) the  smoke does not appear. In render preview and image render it shows up. When I render one frame it shows up. When render ing less frames, about 20 it just becomes a blob that shakes. This is in blender 4.3. I am using a principaled volume for shading. The shorter animation results in a volumetric square that jitters but does not follow the baked animation. The domain has location, scale, and rotation applied. The animation works correctly in an image, but not in the animation. I am using the FFmpeg video format.









Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see How to take a screenshot. Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.
